# Gnome Tweak Tool settings not effective on RDP sessions (xfreerdp)

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, remote-desktop

My local machine is a Dell XPS running Ubuntu 18.04.  I remap ctrl and caps via the Gnome Tweak Tool (Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Ctrl Position -> Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock).  Works perfectly well.  I am required to access certain hosts via RDP sessions (no ssh).  The host is CentOS 7.  I have tried several RDP clients and xfreeRDP seems to be working best.  However, this program does not pass my keyboard mapping to the target CentOS host.

Inside the CentOS 7 host, I can open the Gnome Tweak Tool and apply the same setting as I use on Ubuntu, but it doesn't take effect.  I've tried logging out, restarting, etc.  I've also tried many other techniques to remap inside the RDP session, but none of them seem to have any effect (e.g., setxkbmap, xmodmap).  I don't see any errors either.

Anyone know why these kinds of settings don't seem to take effect and/or how to resolve it?  My current plan is to follow some instructions to compile xfreeRDP from source and modify the code's keyboard layout as described [here](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/505), but that's not a great solution.